# Regex - Remove everything before first comma and everything after second comma in line

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have the following string:

```
55,1001wuensche.com,0,354137264,1,"0.00 %",0,"0.00 %","2016-04-24 09:00:24"
56,100hoch3.de,47,2757361,2,"0.00 %",0,"0.00 %","2016-02-11 00:42:10"
```

I want to remove everything before the first comma: `55,` and `56,`

AND everything after the second comma.

The result should look like this, where only the domain name is left:

```
1001wuensche.com
100hoch3.de
```

I'm using Notepad++ to accomplish this. Anybody got an idea? Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Have you tried any pattetn yet?

Answer (score 4):

```
^.*?,(.*?),.*$
```

The capture group `$1` will be everything between the first two commas.

Comment: Honestly i don't like answering questions with no effort by OP but life in [tag:regex] is a race

Comment: The last `.*` can be greedy. (Yes, I agree with you. Regex questions seem to get away with this)

Comment: you're right about the greedy, I guess its going to the end of the line anyway

Comment: @WillBarnwell I think you can even also drop the `$`

Comment: @bobblebubble but the `$` doesn't hurt, and probably makes the regex slightly more efficient and idiot-proof ("whoops I had multiline match on")

Comment: If you are using Sublime Text or PHPStorm, then you can use "Find and Replace" in combination with the "Regular Expressions" feature (.*) and just replace all instances of ^.*?,(.*?) with nothing

Answer (score 2):

You could search for `^[^,]+,([^,]+).*` and replace it with `$1`.

If there is a chance of non-well formatted lines (containing empty strings before the first comma or lines without comma) you could use a more strict pattern like `^[^,\r\n]*,([^,\r\n]+).+` instead.

Comment: this fails if the first grouping is blank

Comment: If there are lines without a comma before they will get removed too.

Comment: @WillBarnwell is was assuming well formatted input.. edited for weirder cases

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Given the OP's requirements, that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this sort of thing *(in a more general sense)* is to "`split` the line by commas, into an array, then take only the second element of that array.

Yet-another way to do it is to execute two "substitute" regexes, both explicitly anchored to the beginning or to the end of the line (and the first being *non-*"greedy" e.g.:

```
s/^.*\?,//

s/\,.*$//
```

The concept of "greediness" is quite important, because in the first case we want to match the *least* number of characters, so as to stop at the *first* comma that is encountered. (Hence, "non-greedy.") Whereas, in the second case, you *do* want to "greedily" identify (and set to empty-string) the biggest match that you can find: namely, "the rest of the string."

Find the *simplest* and *most obvious* way to do it, because, quite inevitably, someone's going to want to change this logic someday. Or, someone will hand you a file that breaks your "clever, elegant" approach. Think "testable, and maintainable."